# How to make a List with 3 columns in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, types, datatable

How to make a `List` with 3 columns in C#?

Each columns must have a different `type`.

Now I have tried this.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<decimal> list2 = new List<decimal>();
List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
```

How can I combine this in one `List`?

In order to read it in one `for`, and access it.

Comment: What do you mean by columns? What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by 3 columns ? List<T,T,T> ?

Comment: How about a List of a defined type that has three properties?

Comment: Do you want to create  a datatable with 3 columns??

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Is it a list of objects that hold 3 properties with different types. For that purpose you need to create a class, that will hold these properties and then initialize a List of that type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) of [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) for that, using list initializer

```cs
var list = new List<(int item, string data, decimal value)>
{
    (1, "test", 1.2m),
    (2, "test", 3.6m)
};
```

or using `for` loop

```cs
var list = new List<(int item, string data, decimal value)>();

foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 3)) 
    list.Add((item, $"data{item}", item));
```

And access an items like that

```cs
var item = list.FirstOrDefault();
var data = item.data;
```

But keep in mind, that named tuples are available starting from C#7

Comment: @LopDev does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Comment: how to add more that one items although, with a while loop? Because , I tried this , this is nice way but when I add the through a while loop , it always keeps the last itemObject and fills all the previous with the same values , I tried this with the class option

Comment: @LopDev you can use `Add` method to add a new item. It seems, that you aren't updating the data inside loop. I've tried with `for` loop and it works as expected

Comment: @LopDev "it always keeps the last itemObject and fills all the previous with the same" please post the code, it sounds like you have a shallow copy.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , i tried your answer in asimple for loop and it worked! Great.  ,  My question is about , if i use the class option

Comment: @LopDev with class you have to create a new instance in a loop every time, before adding to a list, e.g. `var myClass = new MyClass();` inside `while` loop, not before

Comment: ItemsClass.item1 = value;
ItemsClass.item2 = value;
ItemsClass.item3 = value;                                                                                                  list.Add(ItemsClass);     I do this in a while loop an always fills alll the  list with  the last object.

Comment: `ItemsClass` instance must be created (inside a loop) before assigning its properties, `var ItemsClass = new ….`, otherwise you've modified the same instance

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Thank you so much! I have fogrotted this...I marked your answer as the answer , thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own custom class with the property that you want and then make a list out if it

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int ItemA { get; set; }
        public string ItemB { get; set; }
        public bool ItemC { get; set; }
    }

List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

and to add an item to the class you simply create a new instance of the class and add it to the list

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass
{
    ItemA = 1,
    ItemB = "hello",
    ItemC = true
 };

 myList.Add(myClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to create a list that contains three different variables you could also consider creating an object class that holds those values;

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string StringProperty { get; set; }
   public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
   public decimal DecimalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then creating a list like so:

```
List<MyObject> NewList = new List<MyObject>();
```

You can then add new items to this object by calling the add command on that list:

```
MyObject TempObject = new MyObject();
TempObject.StringProperty = "Foo";
TempObject.IntegerProperty = 2;
TempObject.DecimalProperty = 0.3;
NewList.Add(TempObject);
```

If you mean three seperate types in a list, then refer to what Pavel said on tuples.

Comment: how to add more that one items although, with a while loop? Because , I tried this , this is nice way but when I add the through a while loop , it always keeps the last itemObject and fills all the previous with the same values

Comment: @LopDev "it always keeps the last itemObject and fills all the previous with the same" please post the code, it sounds like you have a shallow copy.